# Get CommandButton name/ID in a cell

Tags: excel, vba, commandbutton

I have a spreadsheet with CommandButtons in cells. I would simply like to Get the name/ID of the commandbutton in a particular cell without a button being clicked. 
How could I go about it ? 
I have been using this code but its inefficient as I have to type every button ID one by one. I have about 60 buttons.

```
 Sub Worksheet_Calculate()

  If Cells(6, 3).Value = 0 Then

    Me.Buttons("Button 55").Enabled = False
    Me.Buttons("Button 55").Font.ColorIndex = 16
Else
    Me.Buttons("Button 55").Enabled = True
    Me.Buttons("Button 55").Font.ColorIndex = 1

    End If

    If Cells(7, 3).Value = 0 Then

    Me.Buttons("Button 61").Enabled = False
    Me.Buttons("Button 61").Font.ColorIndex = 16
Else
    Me.Buttons("Button 61").Enabled = True
    Me.Buttons("Button 61").Font.ColorIndex = 1

    End If
```

Answer (score 1):

One way would be to loop through all the buttons on the worksheet and check the TopLeftCell for a match to your cell.  Might bog down for a lot of buttons but I think 60 would run fine.  May run into problems if you have overlapping buttons but you can probably avoid that.  This looks at all `Shapes`, it's possible to narrow it down some but I wasn't sure which type of button you're using.

```
'In a worksheet module change Me. to a worksheet as needed.
Function findShape(r As Range) As String
    Dim s As Shape

    findShape = "Not Found" 'if loop goes all the way around and doesn't find it.

    For Each s In Me.Shapes
        If s.TopLeftCell.Address = r.Address Then
            findShape = s.Name
            Exit For 'no need to keep going
        End If
    Next
End Function
```