# Get command button by using cell address

Tags: excel, vba

I want to call/ activate a button at the end of a Sub. I know the cell address of the command button, but I don't know the name/ID of the button.
How do I select/activate the button **without** looping through each button on active sheet?
https://stackoverflow.com/a/30600479/13049793

I have created my buttons on multiple rows with each assigned to the same macro, from my understanding, I cannot call the macro the button is assigned to because the macro uses the button's relative position, below is a simple example to illustrate the use of the buttons relative position:

```
Sub ExampleButtonClick()
 Dim Cellvalue As String
 Cellvalue = ActiveSheet.Buttons(Application.Caller).TopLeftCell.Offset(0, -1).Value
 Msgbox (Cellvalue)
End Sub
```

Comment: This seems like it might be an XY problem... what are you actually doing in your Sub?

Comment: Hi @BigBen I got two Subs, one imports data into Excel, the other exports the data. They use file and folder location stored in adjacent cells to the buttons. I now wish to reduce the button click by calling the export button at the end of my import Sub.

Comment: Well then you already presumably have the adjacent cells as range variables?

Comment: @BigBen yes, the adjacent cells are currently known. I wish to let Row A Button1 to call Row A Button2 & Row B Button1 to call Row B Button2. I basically copy and paste the buttons onto each row.

Comment: Rewrite your sub that exports to take a range as a parameter. Then have the buttons call that sub based on the `TopLeftCell` logic you already have. That way you can keep the buttons' functionality, but also just call the export sub passing it the appropriate range.

Answer (score 0):

i assume you want to run one macro that at the end initiates a different macro, i also assume the reason the button is rather not as a sub that is just called is because it has its independent function that can be used without the other sub

assuming that you used a command button as an activeX control, why not just use a private sub that the button performs and place that in an individual module and at the end of your current sub;

```
call module1 'assuming the private sub exists in module 1
```

or rather include the code even if duplicated in the first sub, searching for a button seems the circular route unless there is another intention you wish to pursue.

maybe elaborate on the task at hand or post the current code you are working on?